# Can we use DFA to parse regular language specified by Context-Free Grammar and generate the parse tree?

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar, regular-language, dfa, parse-tree

As we know, DFA can be used to validate the strings in a regular language.

Example 1. L=ac(b)*bcb|ad(b)*bb.   A string "acbbbcb" can be validated by a DFA as correct.

Also, sometimes, a regular language can be expressed by CFG.

Example 2.

- S -> "a" A "b"
- A -> "c" B "c" | "d" B
- B -> "b" B | "b"

The language generated by the above CFG is just the regular expression in Example 1.

That means, we can use the DFA to validate the (regular) strings generated by this CFG. However, how could we generate the corresponding parse tree ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but for a while ago I found an "online regular expression visualizer": http://regexvisualizer.apphb.com/

Answer (score 1):

All regular languages have a CFG.

Since a DFA does not have any output beyond accept/reject, it cannot strictly speaking build a parse tree. However, I don't see why one could not have at least some DFA for each language that could be augmented with tree-generating side effects (assuming the grammar is unambiguous).  This likely requires that the DFA is built to mirror the grammar's structure and thus is not necessarily minimal.

If the grammar is ambiguous, then, as Gunther writes, a DFA likely isn't sufficient for tree-building purposes.

Comment: Hi ibid, I think your point that this requires the DFA be built with the mirroring of grammar's production rules, is true and essential.

Answer (score 0):

- S -> "a" A "b"
- A -> "c" B "c" | "d" B
- B -> "b" B | "b"

I think this may be achieved in this way:

Imagine you have several pages of paper. In each page of paper, there is a production rule. And the top-most paper has the rule S -> "a" A "b". And there are two transitions: one is from "A" to the next page of paper, and the other is from the next page of paper to this "A".

In this scheme, when the return transition from the next page to the current page occured, we know the production in the next page is used.

In this way, the DFA can generate the parse tree. However, this DFA is more like a "tree" instead of "graph".

This scheme may not be completely correct. If you find any problem, please let me know.